# Filter Strings Using Ternary operator

Tags: python-3.x, conditional-operator

I need to know why my **option1** works and **option2** doesn't.
I am not after a list comprehension solution or alternative answer.

**Option1** :This works and gives `[23, 23, 34]` which is what I expected

```
list(filter(lambda x: True if x>9 else False, [1,23,23,34]))
```

**Option2** doesnt work.Please note I have multiple strings to check against along list

```
list(filter(lambda x: True if x in ('red', 'oh') else False, ['fred', 'john', 'Nick']))
```

Expected output from **option2** is:

```
['fred', 'john']
```

Comment: And actual output?

Comment: ['fred', 'john'] is my expected output

Comment: I understand that. What is the actual output

Comment: How is either of those items a substring of "red" or "oh"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
True if x in ('red', 'oh') else False
```

Look at x. If x is "Fred", x is *not* in "red" ("red" is in "Fred")
You want the opposite.

```
True if 'red' in x or 'oh' in x else False
```

The total line is

```
list(filter(lambda x: True if 'red' in x or 'oh' in x else False, ['fred', 'john', 'Nick']))
```

While not pretty, this is how you can do it with any number of strings:

```py
names = ['fred', 'john', 'nick']
subs = ['red', 'oh']
list(filter(lambda x: True if any([y in x for y in subs]) else False, names))
```

Comment: Not what I am aster. I know  list comprehension would work but I want to apply ternary operator using filter and lambda as specified.

Comment: That is? It's literally just the lambda part of your filter